# Ubuntu 23.04 fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop

Tags: mount

Hi:  I was having internet connection problems (Fiber Optic) and a page froze. After waiting for a while I turned the computer off :-(  when I turn it on I could not get to the second 2 TB mechanical hard drive where I keep all my work files. The first hard drive is an SSD.

I got this message: Error mounting/dev/sdb2/media/adolfo/INTERNAL: Unknown error when mounting/dev/sdb2

Then I run fdisk -l  and I got a whole page of numbered:

"fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0,1, 2........"

ANY HELP WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED